# Menu not opening as a list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a drop down menu, but it is not displaying as a list like I want.  Instead it is displaying across the top banner of my page. Have tried messing around with the CSS but to no avail.

Just need pointed in the right direction about how this can be displayed in list format.

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 100%;*/ /* disabled for the sake of demonstration and user-friendly troubleshooting */ 
  right: 0%;
  background: #d2eaf2;
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu--open {
  height: auto;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}

.menu a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 6em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="menu menu-toggle">
<div>click</div> <!-- Added for user-friendly troubleshooting -->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#TopTips">Top Tips</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#GetIntoRunning">Get Into Running</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#TryThis">Try This</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="menu-toggle">
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
      $('.menu').toggleClass('menu--open');
    })
  });
</script>
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: where is the object with the class `menu-toggle`. because it works if you add one

Comment: It does work, yes, but its not displaying in a straight down list, its displaying across the page for me.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add the `menu-toggle` class so that we can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

for `.menu` you don't need to specify `float` and `right` value, also it's about rearrangement, bring your `menu-toggle` above `.menu` and add text to the menu this will make it work

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
        $('.menu').toggleClass('menu--open');
    })
});
```

```css
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    background: #d2eaf2;
    top: 50px;
    height:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu--open {
    height: auto;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}

    .menu a {
        color: black;
        display: block;
        padding: 2em 6em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.menu a:hover, .menu a:focus {
 background: #7eadbc;
}
.menu-toggle {
 padding: 1em;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0.5em;
 top: 0.5em;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger">myMenu</div>
</div>    
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#About">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TopTips">Top Tips</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#GetIntoRunning">Get Into Running</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TryThis">Try This</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Or if you don't want a text you can specify a width and height for the `.menu-toggle` and add some css to it, check this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
        $('.menu').toggleClass('menu--open');
    })
});
```

```css
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    background: #d2eaf2;
    top: 50px;
    height:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu--open {
    height: auto;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}

    .menu a {
        color: black;
        display: block;
        padding: 2em 6em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
 
      }

    .menu a:hover, .menu a:focus {
     background: #7eadbc;
    }
    .menu-toggle {
     padding: 1em;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0.5em;
     top: 0.5em;
     cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #222;
    }
.menu-toggle:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 8px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 0.15em;
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0 0 black, 0 0.5em 0 0 black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
</div>    
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#About">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TopTips">Top Tips</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#GetIntoRunning">Get Into Running</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TryThis">Try This</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must edit `.menu` class properties.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
            $('.menu').toggleClass('menu--open');
        })
    });
```

```css
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    background: #d2eaf2;
    float: left;
    height: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu--open {
    height: auto;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
}

.menu a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 2em 6em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover, .menu a:focus {
  background: #7eadbc;
}
.menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.5em;
  top: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;/*Just for test*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#About">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TopTips">Top Tips</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#GetIntoRunning">Get Into Running</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TryThis">Try This</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
</div>
```